# Understanding ket notation and the unitary matrix, what does a/the unitary matrix represent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation

I am reading over this paper http://www.scottaaronson.com/thesis.pdf, specifically page 24 under "Quantum computing cheat sheet". The author is explaining ket notation and how it relates to probabilities.

---

[image]

---

My question is what does the Unitary matrix represent?

From what I can tell the martix represents an "operation", if this is correct what is an "operation"?

I don't think I can ask the next question properly without knowing the answer to the first. But my second question has to do with understand thing sentence.

> Applying a “randomizing” operation to a “random” state produces a
>   deterministic outcome!

The only thing I can really ask about it right now, why are randomizing and random in quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Often times, an operation is something that changes the state of the system, like a measurement. But it can be other things that will change the state of the system.

Answer (score 1):

The unitary matrix as given represents an operation on the Hilbert space of states. It could be a measurement, it could be a symmetry, it could be time evolution, or something else.

It is called "randomizing" here, because it transforms a state of definite spin (the $\lvert 0 \rangle = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right) $ state) into a state of indefinite spin: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lvert 0 \rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lvert 1 \rangle$, where what spin you will measure is distributed 50:50. Nothing about this state is inherently different from the one with the definite state, hence the scare quotes around this state being "random".

Answer (score 1):

All the possible states for your systems are encoded as rays in a Hilbert space. For expample, imagine that we are interested in the spin direction of an electron. The Hilbert space for this system is $\mathcal{H}=\mathbb{C}^2$. We can take an orthonormal basis, for example, the $z$ component of the spin, which it would be represented by the orthonormal vectors $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}$.

Let's suposse that we put the electron on a magnetic field such that its spin goes up, i.e., it's in the state $|0\rangle$. Now, we change the magnetic field so the spin goes down (now it's $|1\rangle$).

How do represent this mathematically?

What we have done is a linear transformation between elements of the Hilbert space. This transformation is characterized by an operator $T$:

$$|1\rangle = T|0\rangle$$

In a matrix representation we have:

$$ \pmatrix{ 0 \\ 1} = U(T) \pmatrix{ 1 \\ 0}$$

where $U(T)$ is the matrix representation of the operator $T$. This matrix is, in fact,

$$ U(T) = \pmatrix{ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0} $$

**So we use matrices operating in the Hilbert space to represent the state changes in our system.**

But, why this matrices need to be unitary? Because we want all our states being normalized to 1 (in order to have all the probabilities normalized to 1), so with unitary matrices we ensure it:

If we have a vector $|\alpha\rangle$ and another one $|\beta\rangle = U|\alpha\rangle$, then

$$ \langle\beta|\beta\rangle = \langle\alpha|U^\dagger U |\alpha\rangle =  \langle\alpha|\alpha\rangle $$

where in the last equality we have used that $U$ is unitary. **Unitarity allows us to have a probabilistic interpretation of the QM.**